Inclusion map from $C^{m+1,\alpha}(\Omega) \to C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega)$
Let $\Omega$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am searching for a reference on compactness of Inclusion map from $i : C^{m+1,\alpha}(\Omega) \to C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega)$ for a natural number $m\ge 0$ and $0<\alpha<1$, where
$C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega) = \{ f \in C^{m}(\Omega) | ||f||_{C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega)} < \infty \}$,
$$||f||_{C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega)} = \sum_{|\beta| \le k} ||{D^{\beta}f}||_{\infty} +\sum_{|\beta| = k} H_{\alpha}(D^{\beta}f) .$$
I looked at this link which was useful, however, the discussion is not compactness. This page shows the inclusion map $C^k([0, 1]) \to C^j ([0, 1])$ is compact if and only if $k > j$.
Explanation of notation: Let $\alpha \in(0,1)$ and define $$H_\alpha(f)=\sup \left\{\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}: x, y \in \Omega, x \neq y\right\},$$ $||f||_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \Omega} |f(x)|$ then $C^\alpha(\Omega)=$ $\left\{f \in C(\Omega) \mid\|f\|_{C^\alpha(\Omega)}=\|f\|_{\infty}+H_\alpha(f)<\infty\right\}. $
Addendum: Found online notes which states the following :(thm 24.14) Let $\Omega$ be a precompact open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n, \alpha, \beta \in[0,1]$ and $k, j \in$ $\mathbb{N}_0$. If $j+\beta>k+\alpha$, then $C^{j, \beta}(\bar{\Omega})$ is compactly contained in $C^{k, \alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$.
I was unable to locate the specific result in the book  Partial Differential Equations by Lawrence C. Evans, as referenced in the course notes. Another post suggests that the theorem requires additional conditions, such as a Lipschitz regularity of the boundary, to hold true.

Does this not follow at once from Arzela-Ascoli?

To my knowledge, I have only seen Arzela-Ascoli in one Dimension. Which is the same as wiki definition.

It generalizes considerably. See here

Yes, I think this can be proven using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I am sure this must be in a functional analysis book that I can refer. @fwd
